# Reporting uncoverable directed simple cycles in digraphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

What is known about cycles in digraphs that can't be member of any of that digraph's vertex disjoint directed cycle covers as illustrated below?

[image: cat's eye graph with uncoverable directed cycles]

in that "cat's eye graph" the green cycle represents the unique directed cycle cover and thus none of the other three directed cycles is in any of the directed cycle covers.

I am especially interested in algorithms for reporting or counting them.